# How do you determine the actual command that is piping into you?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Let's say I have a bash script called `log.sh`.  In this script, I want to read in input from a pipe, but I also want to know the command used to pipe input into me.  Example:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error | log.sh
```

In the shell script, I want to know the command `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error`.

Comment: I am extremely curious as to why you want this.

Comment: My guess is your making some type of GUI program which captures & processes pids?

Comment: I would like to know so I can distinguish where to put the results.  Depending on the command and filename, I would want to perform different actions.

Comment: That sounds like a major violation of the Principle of Least Surprise to me. If the script should do different things under different circumstances, then that should be controlled by a command-line option rather than by where its input is coming from.

Comment: @Dave, I agree.  Let's just say, for the sake of this example, I just want to 'know' what the incoming command is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Akira suggested using `lsof`.

Here's how you could script it:

**whatpipe2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$$
pgid=$(ps -o pgid= -p $pid)
lsofout=$(lsof -g $pgid)
pipenode=$(echo "$lsofout" | awk '$5 == "0r" { print $9 }')
otherpids=$(echo "$lsofout" | awk '$5 == "1w" { print $2 }')
for pid in $otherpids; do
    if cmd=$(ps -o cmd= -p $pid 2>/dev/null); then
        echo "$cmd"
        break
    fi
done
```

Running it:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages | ./whatpipe2.sh
tail -f /var/log/messages
^C
```

---

Another way is using process groups.

**whatpipe1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash    

pid=$$
# ps output is nasty, can (and usually does) start with spaces
# to handle this, I don't quote the "if test $_pgrp = $pgrp" line below
pgrp=$(ps -o pgrp= -p $pid)
psout=$(ps -o pgrp= -o pid= -o cmd=)
echo "$psout" | while read _pgrp _pid _cmd; do
    if test $_pgrp = $pgrp; then
        if test $_pid != $pid; then
            case $_cmd in
            ps*)
                # don't print the "ps" we ran to get this info
                # XXX but this actually means we exclude any "ps" command :-(
                ;;
            *)
                echo "$_cmd"
                ;;
            esac
        fi
    fi
done
```

Running it:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages | ./whatpipe1.sh
tail -f /var/log/messages
^C
```

---

Note they both only work if the command on the left side of the pipe runs for long enough for `ps` to see it.  You said you were using it with `tail -f`, so I doubt this is an issue.

```
$ sleep 0 | ./whatpipe1.sh 

$ sleep 1 | ./whatpipe1.sh
sleep 1
```

Comment: instead of this huge post i would have given a 2nd answer with the lsof-based script. nice work for that one.

Comment: @akira Thanks.  It took a few attempts to make it clean and portable.  Learned a few things about procfs and lsof along the way.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I accepted yours as it gives an answer other people can directly use.  @Akira, you did most of the work, sorry I couldn't accept yours as well.

Answer (score 10):

the pipe will appear as an entry in the list of open filedescriptors of your process:

```
 % ls -l /proc/PID/fd
 lr-x------ 1 xyz xyz 64 Feb 11 08:05 0 -> pipe:[124149866]
 lrwx------ 1 xyz xyz 64 Feb 11 08:05 1 -> /dev/pts/2
 lrwx------ 1 xyz xyz 64 Feb 11 08:05 2 -> /dev/pts/2
 lr-x------ 1 xyz xyz 64 Feb 11 08:05 10 -> /tmp/foo.sh
```

you could also use something like:

```
 % lsof -p PID
 sh      29890 xyz  cwd    DIR   0,44    4096  77712070 /tmp
 sh      29890 xyz  rtd    DIR   0,44    4096  74368803 /
 sh      29890 xyz  txt    REG   0,44   83888  77597729 /bin/dash
 sh      29890 xyz  mem    REG   0,44 1405508  79888619 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
 sh      29890 xyz  mem    REG   0,44  113964  79874782 /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
 sh      29890 xyz    0r  FIFO    0,6         124149866 pipe
 sh      29890 xyz    1u   CHR  136,2                 4 /dev/pts/2
 sh      29890 xyz    2u   CHR  136,2                 4 /dev/pts/2
 sh      29890 xyz   10r   REG   0,44      66  77712115 /tmp/foo.sh
```

so, than you have the inode of the pipe :) you can now search every other process under `/proc/` for that pipe. then you will have the command that is piping to you:

```
 % lsof | grep 124149866 
 cat     29889 xyz    1w  FIFO                0,6          124149866 pipe
 sh      29890 xyz    0r  FIFO                0,6          124149866 pipe
```

in this example, `cat` piped to wards `sh`. in `/proc/29889` you can find a file called `cmdline` which tells you, what exactly was called:

```
 % cat /proc/29889/cmdline
 cat/dev/zero%
```

the fields of the command line are separated by NUL, thus it looks a bit ugly :)

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept.  @Akira, you gave the actual breakdown as to how to determine it, while @Mikel gave me a script.  Way to make things awesome + difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact solution using modern `lsof` on modern Linux distributions:

```bash
cmd=$(lsof -t -p $$ -a -d 0 +E | while read p; do
    [ $p -ne $$ ] && echo "$(tr \\000 " " </proc/$p/cmdline)"
done)
```

This lists the endpoint files (`+E`) of FD 0 on the current shell process (`-p $$ -a -d 0`), then limits the output to PIDs only (`-t`), yielding the PIDs on both sides of the pipe.

Note that:

1. There may be more than one PID found on the source end, e.g. `{ echo Hi; sleep 5 ; } | whatpipe.sh` will likely yield a `bash` (the input subshell) and `sleep 5`.
2. `+E` is only available if `lsof` was compiled with `-DHASUXSOCKEPT`. That should be true for most modern Linux distros, but check your installation anyway with: `lsof -v 2>&1 | grep HASUXSOCKEPT`